# Can we track individual user's screen info using Google Analytics?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-analytics

Is it possible to track each user's screen information using Google Analytics?

For Example, suppose I want to track user A's screen path like Activity  A -> Activity B ->Activity C likewise same for user B is it possible to do so?

I have searched for it but as far as I understand about google analytics there is no specific thing available which gives user wise tracking info

Is there any way to do this type of operation using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check Funnels in firebase analytics which shows something like you looking for. So you creating scenarios which you want to track and it shows you each flow separate. As parts of that flow can be activity A -> B -> C or even clicks/events and whatever you want. Very useful and transparent.

Below the flow i am tracking in my application. It helps me to understand on which step i am loosing users while registration flow.

[image]

Just init events on each screen you need first

```
private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);
```

Then register event with random name. For me it was first_open / registration_starts

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_ID, "main_screen");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);
```

After that in Firebase there is a page funnels. Where you can make a sequence of needed events as you see on my screen shot

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can I get this info specific to the user not in general?